# How to parse the given file?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to have the block (whatever is enclosed b/w `{}`) which has latest `utc` time in it. Remove the duplicate blocks (not lines) and only show the block which has latest `utc` time in it. I want it to be in shell script.

```
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:42.670 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:42.840 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:42.840 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:42.840 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:43.20 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:43.20 UTC"
}
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:43.20 UTC"
}
```

For example: I want the output of given file as:

```
{
     "cat":  "error",
     "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
     "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
     "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:43.20 UTC"
}
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: A shell script seems like the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: you can even suggest a solution in python..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that your file is `te1.txt`:

```
grep 'utc' te1.txt | grep -oP '[[:digit:]].*(?= [[:space:]]*UTC.*)' | sort -k1,2 -ur | head -n1 | xargs -Iregex grep -m1 -B4 -A1 "regex" te1.txt
```

**Example**

```
grep 'utc' te1.txt | grep -oP '[[:digit:]].*(?= [[:space:]]*UTC.*)' | sort -k1,2 -ur | head -n1 | xargs -Iregex grep -m1 -B4 -A1 "regex" te1.txt 
{
    "cat":  "error",
        "topic":    "glp/0/17q2d9v/rq/dev/iox/dio/do",
        "message":  "ERROR in iox_test handle",
        "utc":  "2018-07-12 12:39:43.20 UTC"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the following script (assumption: data file is called file.txt):

```
#!/bin/bash

# - delete all lines without "utc"
# - extract timestamp
# - sort entries
# - save last entry in variable timestamp
timestamp="$(sed '/"utc":/!D;s/.*:\s*"\([^"]*\)"/\1/g' file.txt | sort | tail -1)"

# - print file in reverse order
# - grep timespamp, 1 line before, 4 line after pattern
# - extract last 6 lines
# - reverse order
tac file.txt | grep "$timestamp" -A 4 -B 1 | tail -6 | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

When the blocks are sequential, you want the last block.
With `GNU sed 4.2.2` you can use

```
sed -z 's/.*}\n{/{/' inputfile
```